# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' to custom class

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

While developing in C# for ASP .net 4 in VS2013 using WebForms, I was implementing a custom security object that has been used through out of all my applications. With the upgrading from VS2010 to VS2013, I came to this error that bugged me so much....

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' to type
>   'CustomSecurity.BusinessObject.EmployeeIdentity'

And the code location as follows:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page  
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This is where it fails 
        EmployeeIdentity employeeIdentity = (EmployeeIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
    } 
}
```

This line of code worked in VS2010 but didn't work in VS2013. The code compiles but gives me this error during run time.

**Things I have tried so far:**

1. Converting the CustomSecurity.BusinessObject.EmployeeIdentity to .net 4 assembly
2. Changed code to use Page.User and I still get the same error
3. Read other posts in StackOverflow, no luck in finding an answer....

**My Question:**
What are other suggestions that may resolve my issue?

Comment: Throw a breakpoint at the place where you're setting the current user identity, and see if that's no longer firing. Also, double-check your IIS/IISExpress security, to ensure you're still set up using the correct values for anonymous/Windows/Forms/Basic authentication.

Comment: can you show the code where you are trying to get / store the Current user..? are you using `PrincipalContext` please show the code and where the error is happening

Comment: you should consider using "as type " instead of "(type)"

Comment: @JoeEnos Windows Authenciation Enabled, Anonymous disabled. This is the setting used in my other applications in VS2010.

Comment: @MethodMan Updated the code area to display the actual code

Comment: The applicable code is going to be the thing that sets your current principal to an instance of EmployeeIdentity. It'll probably be in global, or in a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

So from converting the code from VS2010 to VS2013, the changes I need was to add  the following to the Web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <!-- Add a Custom Authentication module  THIS NEEDS TO BE ADDED FOR IIS8 + .NET 4 -->
        <add name="DHAAuthenticationModule" type=" DHA.CustomSecurity.BusinessObject.DHAAuthenticationModule, DHA.CustomSecurity.BusinessObject"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

The reason I am assuming is be the webServer needs to understand object definitions as well.... 
This fixed my error that I encountered. It was really specific I guess.

Any thoughts on this?