# Casting Errors Since Upgrade to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, casting, reference

I've been getting a slough of casting errors since an upgrade to Visual studio 2013. When I say 'upgrade', I mean initially the project was built and maintained in Visual Studio 2010. The project was recently upgraded to a Visual Studio 2012 project and now when working on it in VS2013 I've been getting casting errors that I don't understand.

There are two I'm getting, one of which in particular I'm stuck on.

### The first, which I'm not so worried about

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' to type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal'. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' to type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal'.

Source Error: 
Line 21:     {
Line 22:      // omitted
Line 23:         WindowsPrincipal temp2 = (WindowsPrincipal)WindowsPrincipal.Current.Identity;
Line 24:         //HttpContext temp = (HttpContext)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
Line 25:         CustomClass spindle = (CustomClass)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

 Source File:  C:\My Projects\New Project\Default.aspx.cs    Line:  23 

Stack Trace: 

[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' to type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal'.]
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\My Projects\New Project\Default.aspx.cs:23
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237
```

---

### The second which I am focused on

I'm having the same error issue with another cast but this case is a little more specific. I'm `using` an in-house class that uses `System`, `System.Collections`, `System.Collections.Generic`, and `System.Security.Principal`. The class inherits and implements `MarshalByRefObject` and `IIdentity`.

When I create an instance of my custom class and try assigning it the value `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` I get the cast error which is the same as above. Here is the code.

```
CustomClass temp = (CustomClass)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

string FullName = temp.LastName + ", " + temp.FirstName;
Namelbl.Text = FullName;
```

---

Like I explained earlier, I wasn't having any kind of problem like this when I was working with the project in Visual Studio 2010. Once the project was migrated over for us to use in Visual Studio 2013 these errors started popping up. To be quite honest, if I open the same exact project in Visual Studio 2012, I do not get the errors.

I get the errors when I open the project, build the project, right click the file and select view in browser. This is a web project with C# code-behind. I've tried a dozen different solutions inside the web.cofig file which didn't work as well.

The stack trace is also a little foreign to me so if anyone can decipher that and produce a solution that'd be excellent too.

### Edit

I think I might have found the solution but I don’t know if I’m doing the fix right.
What I found is inside the ‘Properties Pages’ (click the project and hit Shift+F4) under the ‘References’ tab the references to all of the CustomClass are versioned as ‘Auto Update’. If you click one of the Class files and click the ‘Update’ button it spits out an error to the file referencing it in an old location.

If I remove the references from the Properties Page it deletes the dlls out of the Bin folder in the project. So I removed the References that had ‘Auto Update’ in their version column. Copied the dlls from an old project location, but not too old,  to the projects Bin folder. And then added them back using the correct folder path but that didn’t seem to do the trick either. Am I not adding references correctly?

### Edit

I now believe that the links to the references are failing. I am now getting errors when I try to view reports that were created in Visual Studio 2013 that use `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`. Though the GAC is referenced, it seems as though it's still not found. The error I'm getting is

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Which seems awfully similar to

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity' to type 'CustomClass'.
```

Maybe it can't cast it to the CustomClass because *it doesn't know what/where it is!*

Comment: Can you take your entire solution before the upgrade, and do a full recursive comparison with it now? Specifically see if there's any change in the csproj or web.config files that are suspect.

Comment: Maybe this is the same problem/solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28951779/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-security-principal-windowsidentity-to-cus

Comment: @JoeEnos I'll look into that and post back the results into the original question.

Comment: @Ulric practically identical but that answer did not resolve the issue. I thought for a little while that maybe it does have something to do with VS2013 using IIS8 Express instead of maybe IIS7. I tried changing the .NET framework too thinking that was it but that was not the case. I'm betting I'll find out what version of IIS are running between the two when I do the full recursive comparison.

Comment: This sounds like a dll version mismatch.  Have you cleaned the solution and verified that the versions of included dlls are what you think they are?  If you are pulling from the GAC, make sure that you don't also have an old dll version referenced as well.

Comment: @DavidL I've looked at the references already. Originally the dlls that were being referenced were versioned as 'Auto' or 'Auto-Update' (whatever it was) so when I would try to update them the reference was broken and would error out. I removed them and then added them again so that they were pointing to the right location. Now the 'version' reads an actual version such as '1.0.0.0' or '1.0.4783.29716'. Perhaps I didn't go about re-adding these dlls in the correct fashion?

Comment: @gh0st I'd remove the dlls again, then -> Add Reference -> Assemblies -> System.Security.  You should be using the 4.0 version.  That should be the only System.Security reference that is added.

Comment: @DavidL didn't seem to do the trick but I'm going to do the full recursive comparison and see what that yields too. The dlls I mentioned were references to the dlls that provide the CustomClass that are  in the `using` statements. Their type is 'BIN' and not 'GAC'.

Comment: There were very little, to no differences between the two projects @JoeEnos. Only a few extra lines added to the .sln solution file to make it a VS2012 project (I think...)

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: What really kills me is that the casting was working fine when building all the way through Visual Studio 2012. Now when I try to build in VS2013 the cast no longer works. Did they get rid of casting in VS2013???

Comment: @DavidL Is there another way of adding dll references to a project? I'm getting a new error when trying to view a report which references `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms`. I've made an edit to the original question.

Comment: @gh0st Nope, there's really only one "right" way to add references to a VS managed project, which is right click references - add reference.  That said, it sounds like perhaps you should tackle the ReportViewer problem first.  Reinstall the ReportVewier to your machine first and see if you can at least get that to resolve: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=8A166CAC-758D-45C8-B637-DD7726E61367&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

An update to my custom class resolved the issue.